# React TypeError: Cannot destructure property as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-props

Any problem with this code?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      name: '',
      gender: '',
      age: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { steps } = this.props;
    const { name, gender, age } =steps;
    this.setState({ name, gender,age });

  }
```

the error shows like this :

[image]

**isn't it defined in the `this.state`  block right above?**

**Full code here:**

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      age: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { steps } = this.props;
    const { name,age } = steps;
    this.setState({ name, age });
  }

 render() {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
   
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>{name.value}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>{age.value}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

SimpleForm.js

```
const steps = [
      {
        id: '1',
        message: 'What is your name?',
        trigger: 'name',
      },
      {
        id: 'name',
        user: true,
        trigger: '5',
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        message: 'How old are you?',
        trigger: 'age',
      },
      {
        id: 'age',
        user: true,
        trigger: '7',
      },
      {
        id: '7',
        message: 'Great! Check out your summary',
        trigger: 'review',
      },
      {
        id: 'review',
        component: <App />,
        asMessage: true,
        end: true,
      }
    ]


class simpleForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ChatBot steps={steps} />
        )
     }
}

export default simpleForm;
```

Comment: What is defined in your component's props? Or to be precise, how does `this.props.steps` look like?

Comment: @wentjun it is primary chatbot steps, i want to catch user inputs ((name, gender, age)) into chatbot dialog, and render them onto the screen. The chatbot component refers from here (https://lucasbassetti.com.br/react-simple-chatbot/#/docs/hello-world). am i answer your questions?

Answer (score 5):

The error is clear. You're not sending any props to the App component, so { *steps* } is undefined, and you can't destructure the property "steps" because it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` is now a deprecated life cycle method and will be removed in version 17. [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

One option is defining defaults into the state from props.
e.g.

```js
this.state = {
  name: this.props.steps.name || '',
  gender: this.props.steps.gender || '',
  age: this.props.steps.age || ''
}
```

You could also set it to state after `componentDidMount`.

Comment: works when i change into new state, but the under

render() {
     const { name, gender, age } = this.state;   
     return ( {name.value} ) 
}  

not show up anything?

Comment: Do you have a full example of the code? It can be hard to see what is going on with snippets here and there.

Comment: Sure will add on the original post :D